# Selector up first not visible div

Tags: prototypejs

This works:

```
$('myform').up('div[display:none]')
```

I'm looking for the first ancestor div element who's display is none however I'm wondering if this is cross-browser.  Is it?

Thanks.

Karl..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `[]` CSS selector is for attributes and not styles.

you could do

```
$('myform').up('div[style~="display:none"]')
```

but it wont be as reliable as you think

Comment: OK thanks for the feedback.  I'll just walk my ancestors and test the visibility.